# Something like MutationObserver for observing changes to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mutation-observers

I have an object, which I modify on a regular basis. As data is discovered and discarded, I add items to and delete items from the nested arrays.

```
let obj = {
  image: [],
  video: []
}
```

I am wondering if there is anything like `MutationObserver` that is instead capable of monitoring changes to objects?

If not, is there a way to monitor an object for changes without manually polling it constantly?

Comment: Proxy [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: The way I've seen a lot of systems handle this problem is by using explicit `set` methods and even those have their problems in detecting changes. For instance `var x = {stuff: []}; var y = x.stuff; y[0] = 'thing'; x.set('stuff', y);` Most "setter" systems fail to detect that change as the underlying array is still the same object.

Comment: @gforce301 is it possible to do in a foolproof manner tho? or at least if i determine how the arrays are modified?

Comment: It just depends on how you define "foolproof" and what level of "un-efficiency" you're willing to accept. Even using a proxy to trap the setting of property values suffers from the same problem as in my comment above.

Comment: @gforce301 u got me scared, so i found a way around it which is sufficient for the time being :)